# Jquery append and modify each of same class

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am trying to take content from a nav bar, and then modify and append it to a mobile menu.  The nav bar html looks like

```
  <div id="top_bar" class="nav">
                <div class="container">
                    <div class="row">
                        <nav class="clearfix">
                            <a href="http://127.0.1.1:8080/my-account" class="top-bar-link"><span>My Account</span></a>
                            <a href="http://127.0.1.1:8080/" class="top-bar-link"><span> Rewards</span></a>
                            <a href="http://127.0.1.1:8080/" class="top-bar-link"><span>Customer Service</span></a> 
                        </nav>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
```

I need to append the anchors above to the following menu and have them work in the format below.

```
<ul id="stmobilemenu" class="visible-xs visible-sm show">
    <li class="stmlevel0"><a href="http://127.0.1.1:8080/first" style="" class="ma_level_0">first</a></li>
    <li class="stmlevel0"><a href="http://127.0.1.1:8080/second" style="" class="ma_level_0">second</a></li>
    <li class="stmlevel0"><a href="http://127.0.1.1:8080/third" style="" class="ma_level_0">third</a></li>
</ul>
```

I tried to do this like

```
   var add_to_menu;
   $('#top_bar nav a').each(function(){  
        var line  = '<li class="stmlevel0">';
        $(this).addClass('ma_level_0'); 
        line += $(this).html();
        line += '</li>';
        add_to_menu += line;

})
   $('#stmobilemenu').append(add_to_menu);
```

The result of this was it added undefined, then it added only the content
so appeneded was in this type of format.

```
<li class="stmlevel0"><span>My account</span></li>
```

what I want it to add is in this type

```
<li class="stmlevel0"><a href="http://127.0.1.1:8080/my-account" style="" class="ma_level_0"><span>My account</span></a></li>
```

Another thing I tried was

```
$('#stmobilemenu').append(
    $('#top_bar nav a').each(function(){            
        $(this).prepend('<li class="stmlevel0">'); 
        $(this).addClass('ma_level_0');   
        $(this).append('</li>');         
}));
```

I had a few problems with this though, first of all the append and prepend were not actually surrounding the html I want.  It comes out like

```
<a href="http://127.0.1.1:8080/my-account" class="top-bar-link ma_level_0">
    <li class="stmlevel0"></li>
    <span>My account</span>
</a>
```

So I need that li to actually surround the a.  Also it actually removed the content of `#top_bar nav a` from its original spot, which is not what I want it to do.  I want it only to copy and add to the mobile menu. Can someone help?

Comment: note that any insertion method only works with a complete element. The last one trying to add open/close tags can't be done as you would in an html editor

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use **[clone()](http://api.jquery.com/clone/)** to make a copy of each `<a>`

```
var $mobMenu= $('#stmobilemenu');// store reference to menu element

$('#top_bar nav a').each(function(){
    var $link = $(this).clone().removeClass().addClass('ma_level_0'); 
    $('<li class="stmlevel0">').append($link).appendTo( $mobMenu);          
});
```

Answer (score 0):

```js
var anchors = $('#top_bar nav').children();

anchors.each(function(){
  var $this = $(this),
      $li = $('<li class="stmlevel0"></li>');
  
  $this.removeClass().addClass('ma_level_0').appendTo($li);
  $li.appendTo('#stmobilemenu');
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="top_bar" class="nav">
  <div class="container">
    <div class="row">
      <nav class="clearfix">
        <a href="http://127.0.1.1:8080/my-account" class="top-bar-link"><span>My Account</span></a>
        <a href="http://127.0.1.1:8080/" class="top-bar-link"><span> Rewards</span></a>
        <a href="http://127.0.1.1:8080/" class="top-bar-link"><span>Customer Service</span></a> 
     </nav>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>

<ul id="stmobilemenu" class="visible-xs visible-sm show">
    <li class="stmlevel0"><a href="http://127.0.1.1:8080/first" style="" class="ma_level_0">first</a></li>
</ul>
```